# Trying to Use ORDER BY on a LEFT JOIN Query

Tags: sql-server, group-by, left-join, sql-order-by

I am trying to use a left join and concat 2 column names so that they display together in a dropdown list. This is my query so far.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(Index.MR_ID AS INT),' - ', Master.MR_Name) AS MR_ID
FROM Index
LEFT JOIN Master
ON Master.MR_ID=Index.MR_ID
```

I want to order it by the MR_ID in the Index table but whenever I try to add an ORDER BY to the query, it will not work for me. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: we could....if you show what `ORDER BY`  clause you were trying to use

Comment: first of all you have `Index.MR_Id` in several places in the SQL above, but `Index` is not a table mentioned in the From clause. Is it supposed to be `SINdex`? Or should it be `Index` in the From clause? and is that your problem in your Order By ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(Index.MR_ID AS INT),' - ', Master.MR_Name) AS MR_ID
FROM [Index]
LEFT JOIN Master
ON Master.MR_ID=Index.MR_ID
)
SELECT *
FROM
    cte
ORDER BY
    MR_ID;
```

The above is if you want to order by the final column you got.

If you want to order by the MR_ID in the Index or Master table, it is not possible because you are using the DISTINCT operator, which means it is undetermined by the final query. In that case, you will need the below

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(Index.MR_ID AS INT),' - ', Master.MR_Name) AS MR_ID
    , Index.MR_ID AS sort_column
FROM [Index]
LEFT JOIN Master
ON Master.MR_ID=Index.MR_ID
)
SELECT MR_ID
FROM
    cte
ORDER BY
    sort_column;
```

Comment: This is what im looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think your after this

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(Index.MR_ID AS INT),' - ', IsNull(Master.MR_Name, '')) AS MR_ID
FROM SIndex
LEFT JOIN Master ON Master.MR_ID=SIndex.MR_ID
Order by CONCAT(CAST(Index.MR_ID AS INT),' - ', IsNull(Master.MR_Name, ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Mister Positive beat me to it. I'd also prepare for nulls since you are using a left join.

```
select distinct concat(cast(index.mr_id as int),' - ', isnull(master.mr_name,'') as mr_id
  from sindex
    left join master on master.mr_id=index.mr_id
  order by concat(cast(index.mr_id as int),' - ', isnull(master.mr_name,'')
```